# How to integrate Cassandra from karate feature file to delete test data

Tags: karate

I am executing different test scenarios in Karate feature file but at the end of my test I want to delete my test data from Cassandra database. Could you suggest me how can I connect Cassandra from Karate and how to execute Data cleanup activity only once after all test case execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) write a Java utility and call it from Karate, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

2) Normally it is safer to clean-up *before* a test and you can use [`karate.callSingle()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks) for this. To do something at the end of a test-suite, it is simplest to do it in the Java runner, similar to how HTML reports are generated: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution