# How to connect to DynamoDb using karate framework

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, karate

I have a scenario to test API in which i need to connect to Dynamo DB(AWS) to validate if data has been created/updated in DynamoDb table. Is there a way/working example of how to connect to DynamoDb using karate framework ?I could find ways to connect to oracle and some other databases but could not find anything related to DynamoDB.

Comment: short answer - use Java interop via the java library for dynamo-db and you can do anything you want. also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526715/143475